# Change table's contents on hover?

Tags: html, css, html-table, hover

I have the table as shown below:

```
<table border="1px" width= "900px" ; height="100px">
                <tr>
                    <td width="200px" height="100px" align="center" >
                     <p><img src="images/home.png"/></p>
                     <p>Room<p></td>
               </tr>
</table>
```

It looks like:

[image: http://imgur.com/0NmtzWM]

What I want to do is when the mouse hover over the content in "td",  the following change happens.

1. The content changes from "Room" to 3 different links that redirect into the different pages.
2. The image remains in the middle with higher opacity.

like:

[image: http://imgur.com/tRke0up]

Comment: I notice you have no `<tbody></tbody>` in table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the elements content on hover, you need to use javascript to do that. But if you want to show another content on hover like what I see on your images, you can hide the `3 links` and show them on hover. Example:

```css
table {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  text-align: center; 
}

td {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.default {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.show-hover {
  background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

a {
  display: block;
}

td:hover .show-hover {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="default">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTUDQgbT9PFaERFaLbqP8sFsyq2r3sSYu6BtCj63z90tLEpALgo" />
        <p>Rooms</p>
      </div>
      <div class="show-hover">
        <div class="wrap">
          <a href="">Lorem</a>
          <a href="">Ipsum</a>
          <a href="">Dolor</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```